# Authentication through Open ID like Google facebook etc

Tags: authentication, openid

I have one application for which i am doing authentication through local ldap server.

How do i make use of OpenID user account authentication for my application?

How to achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your application is web based, you would need to grab one of the many OpenID Relying Party (RP) libraries for whatever language your application is in.  Most of the libraries provide some sample code and documentation to get you started.

Comment: You can find some of the more popular libraries listed here: http://openid.net/developers/libraries/